# Resizing HBITMAP while keeping transparent background

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, hbitmap

I have an application that loads an image with a transparent background, then I use `StretchBlt` to resize it to the desired size, with `HALFTONE` set using `SetStretchBltMode` (I tried using other modes that, while keeping the transparency intact, also made the resized image look 'ugly').
However, `StretchBlt` replaces the transparent background with a color (black) that doesn't fit the background of the window that the image will be displayed on. 
So I have two options: 
1) Replace the transparent background of the image with the background color of the window, then resize it using `StretchBlt`
2) Resize it while keeping the background transparency (preferred option)
I tried looking for WinAPI function that would provide either functionality, but I found none.
How do I do any of those options (replace the transparency or resize it while keeping it) using plain WinAPI?

Comment: "transparent background" is very unspecific - please tell us the exact image format, e. g. "32 bpp ARGB with premultiplied alpha". Also, showing your current code would be helpful.

Comment: It is a GDI function, GDI is stuck at 24bpp and does not support 32bpp image formats.  Consider GDI+, gdiplus.h header file.

Comment: Have a look at the [WIC API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719655(v=vs.85).aspx). GDI is not up to much these days (and GDI+ is rather slow).

Comment: One way to make your image transparent is to get the individual pixels using *GetDIBits* and then merge them with the window background color (pixel by pixel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `BitBlt`, `StretchBlt` and `TransparentBlt` do NOT support the alpha channel..

`TransparentBlt` works by making whatever specified colour you want, transparent.

If you want Alpha channel and blending support, you need: `AlphaBlend`.

You can do the following:

```
BLENDFUNCTION fnc;
fnc.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
fnc.BlendFlags = 0;
fnc.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xFF;
fnc.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

//You need to create a memDC.. and an HBITMAP..

//Select the hBitmap into the memDC.
HGDIOBJ obj = SelectObject(memDC, hBmp);

//Render with alpha blending..
AlphaBlend(DC, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height, memDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, fnc);

//Restore the memDC to original state..
SelectObject(memDC, obj);
```

OR do your own pre-multiplied alpha rendering by calculating the channel colours yourself..

Alternatively, you can try GDI+ and see how that works out:

```
ULONG_PTR GdiImage::GDIToken = 0;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput GdiImage::GDIStartInput = NULL;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&GdiImage::GDIToken, &GdiImage::GDIStartInput, NULL);

Gdiplus::Image* Img = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(L"PathToImage.ext"); //where ext can be png, bmp, etc..

Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(DC);
//graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighSpeed);
graphics.SetInterpolationMode(Gdiplus:: InterpolationModeBilinear); //InterpolationModeNearestNeighbor
//graphics.SetPixelOffsetMode(Gdiplus::PixelOffsetModeHalf);
graphics.DrawImage(Img, x, y, w, h);

delete Img;
Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(GdiImage::GDIToken);
GdiImage::GDIStartInput = NULL;
GdiImage::GDIToken = 0;
```

Comment: This works, but the resulting image is ugly just like with `StretchBlt` without using `HALFTONE`, as described in my question.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you mean by "looks ugly". You don't want to use `HALFTONE`,  but you want to up-scale.. Do you have before and after images? (before scaling, scaling with half-tone, scaling without half-tone).

Comment: @あぶらだこ; I added `GDIPlus` just in case you want to try that.. `GDIPlus` can support Transparent bitmaps, png, etc.. it also has interpolation, smoothing, half-tone and other effects and transformations..

Answer (score 1):

> I tried looking for WinAPI function that would provide either
>   functionality, but I found none.

Although others already gave a few suggestions, to my knowledge none of the currently (12/2017) available native OS APIs provide *high-quality* image resampling.

There are many third-party libraries available for resampling. Many (most?) of them are quite complicated and propably overkill if image processing is not the main job of your application.

In the following example I am using the public-domain, single-header file, no-external-dependencies [**"stb_image_resize.h"**](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_resize.h) library. Just `#include` it in your project and be done with it. The library is not the fastest, but I wouldn't call it particularly slow. Where it shines is ease-of-use and versatility. It is also easy to extend, if you'd like to have additional filters like *Lanczos* (for which I can provide code if there is interest). Though the built-in filters are already much better than the ones of the OS APIs.

The following **sample program** expects to find a 32 bpp bitmap with an alpha-channel (non-premultiplied) in the file "flower.bmp" of the current directory.
The image is loaded using the OS API `LoadImageW()`, resampled to one third of the original dimensions using [`stbir_resize_uint8()`](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/9d9f75eb682dd98b34de08bb5c489c6c561c9fa6/stb_image_resize.h#L209) and stored as "flower_resized.bmp" in the current directory using GDI+.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus" )
namespace gp = Gdiplus;

#define STB_IMAGE_RESIZE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image_resize.h"

int main()
{
    // Using LR_CREATEDIBSECTION flag to get direct access to the bitmap's pixel data. 
    HBITMAP hBmpIn = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP>(
        LoadImageW( NULL, L"flower.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 
                    LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION ) );
    if( !hBmpIn )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load bitmap.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Getting bitmap information including a pointer to the bitmap's pixel data 
    // in infoIn.dsBm.bmBits.
    // This will fail if hBmpIn is not a DIB. In this case you may call GetDIBits() 
    // to get a copy of the bitmap's pixel data instead.
    DIBSECTION infoIn{};
    if( !GetObject( hBmpIn, sizeof( infoIn ), &infoIn ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Bitmap is not a DIB.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Some sanity checks of the input image.
    if( infoIn.dsBm.bmBitsPixel != 32 || infoIn.dsBm.bmPlanes != 1 ||
        infoIn.dsBmih.biCompression != BI_RGB )
    {
        std::cout << "Bitmap is not 32 bpp uncompressed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a DIB for the output. We receive a HBITMAP aswell as a writable 
    // pointer to the bitmap pixel data.
    int out_w = infoIn.dsBm.bmWidth / 3, out_h = infoIn.dsBm.bmHeight / 3;
    BITMAPINFO infoOut{};
    auto& hdr = infoOut.bmiHeader;
    hdr.biSize = sizeof(hdr);
    hdr.biBitCount = 32;
    hdr.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    hdr.biWidth = out_w;
    hdr.biHeight = out_h;  // negate the value to create top-down bitmap
    hdr.biPlanes = 1;
    unsigned char* pOutPixels = nullptr;
    HBITMAP hBmpOut = CreateDIBSection( NULL, &infoOut, DIB_RGB_COLORS, 
        reinterpret_cast<void**>( &pOutPixels ), NULL, 0 );
    if( !hBmpOut )
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create output bitmap.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Resample the input bitmap using the simplest API. 
    // These functions use a "default" resampling filter defined at compile time 
    // (currently "Mitchell" for downsampling and "Catmull-Rom" for upsampling). 
    // To change the filter, you can change the compile-time defaults 
    // by #defining STBIR_DEFAULT_FILTER_UPSAMPLE and STBIR_DEFAULT_FILTER_DOWNSAMPLE, 
    // or you can use the medium-complexity API.
    // Consult "stb_image_resize.h" which contains the documentation.

    stbir_resize_uint8( 
        reinterpret_cast< unsigned char const* >( infoIn.dsBm.bmBits ), 
        infoIn.dsBm.bmWidth,
        infoIn.dsBm.bmHeight,
        0,  // input_stride_in_bytes, 0 = packed continously in memory
        pOutPixels,
        out_w,
        out_h,
        0,  // output_stride_in_bytes, 0 = packed continously in memory
        4   // num_channels
    );

    // Use GDI+ for saving the resized image to disk.

    gp::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdipToken = 0;
    gp::GdiplusStartup( &gdipToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr );

    {
        gp::Bitmap bmpOut( hBmpOut, nullptr );
        // I'm taking a shortcut here by hardcoding the encoder CLSID. Check MSDN to do it by-the-book:
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533843(v=vs.85).aspx
        class __declspec(uuid("{557cf400-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}")) BmpEncoderId;
        bmpOut.Save( L"flower_resized.bmp", &__uuidof(BmpEncoderId) );
    }

    // Cleanup
    gp::GdiplusShutdown( gdipToken );
    DeleteObject( hBmpIn );
    DeleteObject( hBmpOut );

    std::cout << "All done.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

When resampling transparent images, it is generally advisable to use a [premultiplied alpha channel](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre). Otherwise the resampled image can have artifacts, generally noticable along the edges of shapes. STBIR will use "alpha-weighted resampling" (effectively premultiplying, resampling, then unpremultiplying) unless you specify the `STBIR_FLAG_ALPHA_PREMULTIPLIED` flag. So you will gain performance benefits when manually premultiplying once after loading an image. Most Windows APIs (like `AlphaBlend`) that can show transparent images, expect the alpha channel to be premultiplied anyway.